Selenium chrome driver does not load dynamic content?
I have an integration test that checks if the Swagger UI of the application is accessible.
I set up my Chrome driver like this:
chrome = new BrowserWebDriverContainer<>()
        .withCapabilities(new ChromeOptions().setHeadless(true));
    chrome.start();
    driver = chrome.getWebDriver();
    driver
        .manage()
        .timeouts()
        .implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

And in my test:
String url = String.format("http://host.testcontainers.internal:%d/swagger#/%s", servicePort, endpointPath);
driver.get(url);
waitForLoad(driver);

  private void waitForLoad(WebDriver driver) {
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> pageLoadCondition = driver1 -> {
      return Objects
          .requireNonNull(driver1)
          .getPageSource()
          .contains("Try it out");
    };
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    wait.until(pageLoadCondition);
  }

The waitForLoad() function eventually times out, and I can see that the driver.getPageSource() only returns the skeleton of the web page, but no dynamic content. When I open the same swagger on localhost, it loads without issues.
Tried it with higher timeouts and headless=chrome option, but got the same result.
Chrome driver Capabilities:
{
  acceptInsecureCerts: false,
  acceptSslCerts: false,
  applicationCacheEnabled: false,
  browserConnectionEnabled: false,
  browserName: chrome,
  chrome: {
    chromedriverVersion: 2.43 .600233(523 efee95e3d68..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...
    },
    cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
    databaseEnabled: false,
    goog: chromeOptions: {
      debuggerAddress: localhost: 35709
    },
    handlesAlerts: true,
    hasTouchScreen: false,
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    locationContextEnabled: true,
    mobileEmulationEnabled: false,
    nativeEvents: true,
    networkConnectionEnabled: false,
    pageLoadStrategy: normal,
    platform: LINUX,
    platformName: LINUX,
    rotatable: false,
    setWindowRect: true,
    takesHeapSnapshot: true,
    takesScreenshot: true,
    unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ,
    unhandledPromptBehavior: ,
    version: 70.0 .3538 .77,
    webStorageEnabled: true,
    webdriver.remote.sessionid: 694e7496 e5aa8c005ef9421e3b1...
  }

